# How to do a minor upgrade of PostgreSQL on Windows, e.g. 9.3.0 to 9.3.1?

Tags: postgresql, installation, upgrade, postgresql-9.3

What is the recommended way to perform a minor upgrade from PostgreSQL e.g. 9.3.0 to 9.3.1 using the Enterprise DB built windows installer?  Should I uninstall first or just install over the existing installation?

The current installation was performed with postgresql-9.3.0-1-windows-x64.exe.  Now I want to upgrade using postgresql-9.3.1-1-windows-x64.exe.

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/migration.html): stop the server , install the new binaries, and restart.  It is always a good idea to take a backup, and generally, to have a plan B.

Comment: Thanks for the link @dezso, I had read that section of the 9.3 manual but found it a bit vague, especially with regard to the Windows setup binaries.

Comment: @buzz3791 The question/title is inaccurate now because 10.0 to 10.1 is a minor upgrade with the new versioning scheme.  I think that you should remove the `e.g. ...` part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows, simply stopping the postgresql service, then running postgresql-9.3.1-1-windows-x64.exe on top of the existing 9.3.0 works.  No uninstall necessary.  Of course, a backup is recommended.

Clear, explicit documentation for the update procedure on Windows is absent.  Note that the documentation link provided by @dezso has been moved in the current manual to:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html

The PostgreSQL Release Notes typically document migration tips in Appendix E.
For example,

- Appendix E. Release Notes https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html
- Section E.1. Release 10.1, subsection E.1.1. Migration to Version 10.1
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-10-1.html#idm46428658121200

The best source of Windows installer information was the Enterprise DB forums.  Here are some posting I found that addressed the question...

- 2010 April - What's the right way to upgrade to a new version of PostgreSQL
  https://web.archive.org/web/20121210220213/http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2246.page
- 2009 September - Upgrade procedure when using one-click installer?
  https://web.archive.org/web/20130603094838/http://forums.enterprisedb.com:80/posts/list/1906.page#6791

The upgrade info moves around from release to release.  For example,

- Version 10 location:
  Chapter 18. Server Setup and Operation, section 18.6. Upgrading a PostgreSQL Cluster
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/upgrading.html
- Version 9.3 location:
  Chapter 17 Server Setup and Operation, section 17.6 Upgrading a PostgreSQL Cluster
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html
- Version 9.0 location:
  Chapter 24 Backup and Restore, section 24.4 Migration Between Releases
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/migration.html

As of June 2017, EnterpriseDB replaced their community discussion forums affecting the links in this answer(https://web.archive.org/web/20171021012954/https://www.enterprisedb.com/news/enterprisedb-announces-new-postgres-rocks-online-user-forum).  I was able to hunt down some of the original posts on the Wayback Machine.  One dead link that I was unable to repair is: "2010 January - Upgrading to 8.4.2 from 8.4.1",
http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2115.page#7888.

Answer (score 6):

For the record, running the installer for Windows from Enterprise DB (the default, [linked from the Postgres site](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)), at least since the current version Postgres 9.4, you don't have to stop the `postgresql` service. The installer does that for you. You still need to re-establish connections, if any (most clients do this automatically).

Best refer to the *current* manual (using the *current* version of Postgres):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/upgrading.html

Answer (score 4):

I just upgraded Postgres 10.0 to 10.1 and it was a very fast and easy upgrade.

I downloaded the binaries from https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries and unzipped them to `C:\postgres`, then renamed the directory `pgsql` to `pgsql-10.1` so that I can keep older versions until deemed unnecessary.

I copied the dll files `msvcp120.dll` and `msvcr120.dll` to `C:\postgres\pgsql-10.1\bin` because I prefer that simple installation over the "Installer" which probably adds much more bloat than needed.

I then used this simple batch script which I wrote in the past:

```
set MAJOR_VERSION=10
set MINOR_VERSION=1

set SERVICE_NAME=pgsql-%MAJOR_VERSION%.%MINOR_VERSION%

set PGHOME=C:\postgres\%SERVICE_NAME%
set PGDATA=C:\postgres\pgdata%MAJOR_VERSION%

%PGHOME%\bin\pg_ctl.exe register -N %SERVICE_NAME% -U LocalSystem -S auto --pgdata=%PGDATA%

::: to unregister old service:
::%PGHOME%\bin\pg_ctl.exe unregister -N %SERVICE_NAME%
```

I ran `SELECT version();` in psql to confirm the old version:

> ```
> postgres=# select version();
> -[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------------------------------------
> version | PostgreSQL 10.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
> ```

I then ran the batch script above which installed a service named `postgres-10.1`.

I stopped the old service and set its `Startup Type` to `Disabled`, and started the new service.

Running `SELECT version();` again in psql confirmed the upgrade (had to run it twice due to the connection being aborted when I stopped the old server):

> ```
> postgres=# select version();
> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>         This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>         before or while processing the request.
> The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
> postgres=# select version();
> -[ RECORD 1 ]-------------------------------------------------------
> version | PostgreSQL 10.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
> ```

Keep in mind that upgrading a major version requires updating the data directory with `pg_upgrade` or some other method, but for a minor upgrade this method worked like a charm.

Comment: Good thing I posted this here.  I just followed the instructions to upgrade from `10.1` to `10.2` and it worked great.