# How to apply a patch to pgAdmin III 1.18.1 on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, upgrade, pgadmin, pgadmin-1.18

A follow-up question to this one: [How to apply a patch in PostgreSQL on Windows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62741/22006)

There is a lot of .patch files distributed everywhere, but no hints how to apply them (at least no hints that wouldn't presume that I am on Linux). Is there any option to install the patch through some GUI? Or do I need to use UNIX-like command line? Or to recompile pgAdmin in Visual Studio? If I need some scripting, point me to some manual, please.

I have pgAdmin III 1.18.1 and PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on Windows XP (32 bit).

EDIT: I'm trying to recompile pgAdmin in Visual Studio (now without the patch - I don't know how to integrate it to the solution, I just try to learn how to recompile it). I reduced the errors raised while trying to rebuild it from 101 to 14, but I have no idea how to handle the rest. So I would appreciate either some tutorial how to recompile pgAdmin in Visual Studio and handle the errors, or any other way how to do it. Or that it is not possible (if so, please back it with some source) and installing Linux and learning with its command line is the only way to apply the patch.

EDIT2: I learnt how to understand the patch code (from a manual [here](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/)) and apply it manually on the file in the sourcecode. Still it looks as though that compilation is necessary, and there are tens of wxwidgets related errors (it just seemed for a while there are just 14 of them).