# Slony-I creation scripts not available; only joining possible

Tags: pgadmin, slony, pgadmin-1.18

I try to start Slony replication. I have PostgreSQL 9.3.4, PgAdmin III 1.18.1 and Slony-I 2.2.0-1. I have set the path to Slony to `D:\GIS\PostgreSQL\9.3\share` where I have the Slony files. Whenever I try to create new Slony-I cluster, there is following message on the bottom of the window: `Slony-I creation scripts not available; only joining possible`.

When looking for solution, I found [a helpful maillist](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pgAdmin-1-18-0-slony-I-2-2-0-PG-9-3-td5772774.html). Especially [first post by Neel Patel](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pgAdmin-1-18-0-slony-I-2-2-0-PG-9-3-tp5772774p5774242.html) was helpful:

> Sorry for the late replay, we have checked and it is a bug in pgAdmin
>   because the name of the sql files got changed in new slony version (
>   v2.2.0 ) which is used by the pgAdmin.
>
> Issue :-
>
> When we install the slony ( version less than 2.2.0 ) then it will
>   install below sql files in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share
>   folder.
>
> slony1_base.sql slony1_base.v83.sql slony1_base.v84.sql
>   slony1_funcs.sql slony1_funcs.v83.sql slony1_funcs.v84.sql
>
> Now in New version of slony 2.2.0 onwards the name of the above sql
>   files got changed as below.
>
> slony1_base.2.2.0.sql slony1_base.v83.2.2.0.sql
>   slony1_base.v84.2.2.0.sql slony1_funcs.2.2.0.sql
>   slony1_funcs.v83.2.2.0.sql slony1_funcs.v84.2.2.0.sql
>
> As we are using above sql files names in pgAdmin to create the new
>   slony clusters so we need to change in pgAdmin also.

Later in the discussion a patch fixing it appeared, but I don't know how to apply it - see [my previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62811/22006). See that question for the ways I tried.

Is there any way to solve this problem other than to install the patch? Help with installing the patch would be also appreciated, but I would prefer it to appear in the linked answer than here, this question should focus on other ways to solve it.

EDIT: I tested different versions of PostgreSQL and Slony-I (Slony 2.0.7 on PostgreSQL 9.1 and Slony 2.1.3 on PostgreSQL 9.2) and also pgAdmin 1.16. The same problems occurs everywhere.